# Get response.data from fetch() as variable to use in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

I've seen several posts about this, so I apologize if it's a direct duplicate. The examples I've seen have the RN components built with classes. I'm using functions, and I'm new, so it's all very confusing.

````
const getFlights = async () => {
  const token = await getAsyncData("token");
  instance({
    method: "get",
    url: "/api/flights/",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
    },
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      // console.log(response.data.results); // shows an array of JSON objects
      return response.data.results; // I've also tried response.data.results.json()
    })```
````

I just want the response returned as a variable that I can use to populate a FlatList component in RN.

```
const FlightListScreen = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const flights = getFlights(); // currently returns as a promise object
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: .then(response => response.json()) 
.then(data => console.log(data));

try this

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to store the response object directly to the json method. And then with that response you can store it to the variable

```
.then(response => { return response.json() })
.then(response => {
this.setState({
list: response
 })
```

Comment: I should've been more clear.

`getData()` is an import into the `FlightListScreen.js` component

So, in `getData()` I tried return` response.data.results.json()` and I get the error:

```Error response.data.results.json is not a function. (In 'response.data.results.json()', 'response.data.results.json' is undefined)
undefined```

My state object is in the file with the component.

Comment: Can you console.log response.json() and tell me what you get?

Comment: ```Error response.json is not a function. (In 'response.json()', 'response.json' is undefined)
undefined```

Answer (score 0):

you are sending token without a bearer. Concrete your token with bearer like this

```
     headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
```

and another thing is your response class are not right this should be like this

```
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    API will Resopne here....
                        }
```

this is a complete example to call API with Token

```
 fetch("/api/flights/", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
          setState(responseJson.VAlue);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      });
```

Comment: The auth header is correct, and I get the desired JSON when I `console.log(response.data.results);`

When I use `response.json()` i get `Error response.json is not a function. (In 'response.json()', 'response.json' is undefined)`